# Pandas is using lot of memory

Tags: pandas

I have flask app code where an API is exposed to dump the data from oracle database to postgress database.
I am using Pandas to copy the content of the tables from oracle, mysql and postgress to postgress. 
After using constantly for 15 days or so, the CPU memory consumption is very high.
It usually transfers atleast 5 million records per two days.

Can anyone help me optimizing pandas write.

Comment: You can read and write in chunks in pandas. See `chunksize` argument here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: Is it your CPU comsumption, or you memory or both that are high ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have some preprocess step, I suggest using dask. Dask offers parallel computation and do not fill memory unless you explicitly force it. The force means computation of any task on dataframe. Refer to documentation [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table) for dask api read_sql_table method.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
# read the data as dask dataframe
df = dd.read_csv('path/ to / file') # this code is subject to change as your
                                    # source changes, just consider this as a 
                                    # pseudo.
{
  # do the preprocess step on data.
}

# finally write it.
```

This solution comes very handy if you have to deal with large dataset with a  preprocessing step possibly a reduction. Refer to documentation [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) for more information. It may have a significant improvement depending on your preprocess step.

Or alternatively, you can use chunksize parameter of pandas as @TrigonaMinima suggested. This allows your machine to retrieve the data in chunks as "x rows at a time" so you may want to process it as above with preprocessing, this may require you to create temp file and append them.